# Getting true selected value of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

I'm currently getting the value of my jTable as everybody does:

```
String  d = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt( jTable1.getSelectedRow() , row ).toString();
```

The thing is that now I'm sorting my jTable with a rowsorter:

```
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(modelo);
jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);

private void filterTable(){
        //If current expression doesn't parse, don't update.
        try {
            rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?iu)"+jFilter.getText(),0,1,2,3,4);//no filtrar la columna con imágenes porque hace cualquiera
        } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }
```

THE PROBLEM:
Once the table is filtered, the function getSelectedRow returns the correct row, but the getModel function returns the original model, not the one after filtering...

THE QUESTION:
How to get the correct value from the table when it is filtered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future wanderers:

The problem was on the way of getting the value from the jTable:

This is wrong when you have a rowsorter:

```
String  d = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt( jTable1.getSelectedRow() , row ).toString();
```

This is what you should be doing:

```
String  d = jTable1.getValueAt( jTable1.getSelectedRow() , row ).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert your "row" value to a model index value, using convertRowIndexToModel.

```
String  d = Table1.getModel().getValueAt(convertRowIndexToModel(jTable1.getSelectedRow()) , column ).toString();
```